# Getting 0 count for my list of elements xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

When try to get the list of spans using the below code I am getting the count as `0`.

```
WebElement listofEntriesAdj = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@style='display: block;']/li"))

List<WebElement> test = listofEntriesAdj.findElements(By.xpath("/div[2]//span[@class='time']"));
```

Comment: If I'm getting it correctly, the element `//div[2]//span[@class='time']` is residing under `//ul[@style='display: block;']/li` element ?

Comment: Can you try with this `List<WebElement> test = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@style='display: block;']/li//div[2]//span[@class='time']"));` directly without using `listofEntriesAdj` element.

Answer (score 1):

I think the xpath that you are using in the seconds statement is incorrect.
Try this:

```
WebElement listofEntriesAdj = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@style='display: block;']/li"))

List<WebElement> test = listofEntriesAdj.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[2]//span[@class='time']"));
```

Comment: Thanks. The path is fine. forgot to put (.) before the XPath.

Comment: It should be 

listofEntriesAdj.findElements(By.xpath("./div[2]//span[@class='time']"));

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@style='display: block;']/li/div[2]//span[@class='time']")
```

Comment: Thanks. Will check with the above XPath.